# Declaring 2 variables

Tags: c++

I would like to ask if it would be possible to declare 2 variables on one line like above (on the same line):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string a, double b;
   int main()
{

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `string a, double b;`? That's not how you declare multiple variables of different type. You need multiple semi-colon separated statements.

Comment: And please stop with the bad habit of using global variables!

Comment: I corrected the variables but the vector seems not to be populated?

Comment: the question is not relative to the title. Please modify your question

Comment: I changed the question because I wanted to ask something else but made a typo and Some programmer dude  said to me that I should make a new question

Comment: please make sure the code you post matches the behaviour you describe before posting. This code does not compile, so "The problem is that my program does not show anything" was at best misleading. Anyhow, voting to close as typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declaration has the wrong syntax.
    `string a, double b;`
should be `string a; double b;`.

If you want to declare two variables with a comma they need to have the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Same variable types: **YES**
Different variable types: **NO**

Different variables need to be on different lines OR separated with a semicolon ; as it signals a new line e.g.

`int a; double b; bool c;`

Which is the same as,

```
int a;
double b;
bool c;
```

If they're the same type you can use a comma , e.g.

```
int a, b, c;
```